# Inconsistent results with remote registry access on 64-bit machines from Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows, 64-bit, registry

I have a test app that creates a key (MyTestKey) on a remote machine (Windows 7 64-bit)under HKLM\Software.
When the test app is executed on a Windows 7 32-bit machine the registry key gets created under \HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\MyTestKey on the 64-bit machine. This is the correct result. But when the test app is executed on a Windows XP SP3 32-bit machine the registry key gets created under \HKLM\Software\MyTestKey on the 64-bit machine, when it should be created under the Wow6432Node key. Same is observed when the remote machine OS is Windows XP SP2 64-bit. Does any one have an idea why this happens? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it's the "correct" result? Isn't that defined by MSDN?

Answer (score 1):

This changed with the [introduction of Server2003/XP64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384237.aspx). It's related to the [Registry Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232.aspx) which has to know whether the caller request redirection. XP32 simply doesn't ask for redirection, so it doesn't get redirection.